# Bootstrap columns not aligning in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a Bootstrap Grid design for my website where I have three columns under the `container-fluid` BS attribute, along with `.row .no-gutters`.

The Boxes are aligned perfectly on the Desktop View, however, when viewed on a mobile or tablet, the boxes are stacked with `width:100%;` which is perfect, except they're not aligned evenly - as Illustrated in the screenshot provided.

I have also changed the CSS on the `@media` attribute by applying the same CSS but removing the padding.

[Screenshot of mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzyWm.jpg)

Here is the code in question:

```css
 /* remove spacing between middle columns */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
/* remove right padding from first column */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:first-child {
  padding-right:5px;
}
/* remove left padding from first column */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:last-child {
  padding-left:5px;
}
.row{
 margin-top: 20px!important;
 margin-bottom: 20px!important;
 display: block;
 height: auto;
}

.legal_section{
 padding: 20px!important;
 background-color: #F5F5F5!important;
 border: 1px solid #EBEBEB!important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well legal_section">
                    <h4>Privacy Policy</h4>
                    <p>Our Privacy Policy explains how we use, collect and protect your data when you use our website.</p>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="../pages/privacy policy.html" class="std_button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well legal_section">
                    <h4>Cookie Policy</h4>
                    <p>Our Cookie Policy tells you about the use of cookies and how you can choose which cookies we collect and process.</p>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="../pages/cookie_policy.html" class="std_button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="well legal_section">
                    <h4>Terms of Use</h4>
                    <p>Our Terms of Use specifies the legal use of our website, what your rights are, and how you can contact us. </p>
                    <br/>
                    <a href="../pages/website-terms-of-use.html" class="std_button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have to remove padding of `col-**-*` classes you have to apply left padding and right padding same and the margin of `row` class should be also have same value but in minus for example: your `col-**-*` class left and right padding is `5px` each then your left and right margin of `row` should be `-5px` each.

Show my snippet for your solution.

```css
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-'] {
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
.row.no-gutter{
  margin-right: -5px !important;
  margin-left: -5px !important;
}
.row{
  margin-top: 20px!important;
  margin-bottom: 20px!important;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
.legal_section{
  padding: 20px!important;
  background-color: #F5F5F5!important;
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="well legal_section">
          <h4>Privacy Policy</h4>
          <p>Our Privacy Policy explains how we use, collect and protect your data when you use our website.</p>
          <br/>
          <a href="../pages/privacy policy.html" class="std_button">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="well legal_section">
          <h4>Cookie Policy</h4>
          <p>Our Cookie Policy tells you about the use of cookies and how you can choose which cookies we collect and process.</p>
          <br/>
          <a href="../pages/cookie_policy.html" class="std_button">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="well legal_section">
          <h4>Terms of Use</h4>
          <p>Our Terms of Use specifies the legal use of our website, what your rights are, and how you can contact us. </p>
          <br/>
          <a href="../pages/website-terms-of-use.html" class="std_button">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats good, it works perfectly in the demo, and in the browser preview when resized to a mobile-size but they're still not aligned when published.

Comment: can you please show me SS for the Published content and its code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of these styles.

```
            /* remove spacing between middle columns */
           .row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
             padding-right:5px;
             padding-left:5px;
           }
           /* remove right padding from first column */
           .row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:first-child {
             padding-right:5px;
           }
```

The first child does not have left padding, whereas the rest of the elements do have it.  Make it all same.